# Custom domain for Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer

On version updates the appspot domain may change for Composer environments. Is it possible to get something static to point a domain to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, adding custom domain and SSL to Airflow is still not possible in Composer. You can follow the progress of this on the [feature request report here](https://issuetracker.google.com/80420564).

Comment: you can't even add custom CNAME to make a proxy.